# How to get scrollbar behind elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an unsorted list with certain width and height.

What I am trying to accomplish is a situation where I click on list item and after that I want it to overflow through scrollbar in list (dont think about making it active, just about overflowing the scrollbar).

Normal scrollbar (XXXX is scrollbar):

```
Item 1 |X|
Item 2 |X|
Item 3 |X|
Item 4 |X|
Item 5 | |
Item 6 | |
Item 7 | |
Item 8 | |
Item 9 | |
```

What I would like after clicking on 3. item

```
Item 1 |X|
Item 2 |X|
   Item 3 
Item 4 |X|
Item 5 | |
Item 6 | |
Item 7 | |
Item 8 | |
Item 9 | |
```

Scrollbar is behind 3. item, and I can move it so if I go down, it will look like this:

```
Item 1 | |        Item 1 | |
Item 2 |X|        Item 2 | |
   Item 3            Item 3 
Item 4 |X|        Item 4 |X|
Item 5 |X|   OR   Item 5 |X|
Item 6 | |        Item 6 |X|
Item 7 | |        Item 7 |X|
Item 8 | |        Item 8 | |
Item 9 | |        Item 9 | |
```

Thank you in advance for any idea

Comment: You can try [**playing with z-index**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/hg7g8sL6/)

Comment: You would have to move the "Item 3" element outside of the container element it's currently in.

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery.jscrollpane.min.js and edit the jquery.jscrollpane.css with z-index...